# Setup richfaces with gradle - NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB

Tags: gradle, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I just created a dynamic web application with gradle and tried to add richfaces.

buildscript:

```
 dependencies {
        compile 'com.sun.faces:jsf-api:2.2.9'
        compile 'com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:2.2.9'
        compile 'jstl:jstl:1.2'
        compile 'org.richfaces.ui:richfaces-components-api:4.3.7.Final'
        compile 'com.google.inject:guice:4.0'

        compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0'
    }
```

the page header

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
```

both taglibs (a4j/rich) are highlighted and the following warning is shown:

```
NLS missing message: CANNOT_FIND_FACELET_TAGLIB in: org.eclipse.jst.jsf.core.validation.internal.facelet.messages
```

Did i forget a step or what am i doing wrong?

I've run the buildscript and refreshed the dependencies. The richface were added to the Web App Libraries. Like in other posts advised i've cleaned, restarted eclipse and opened/closed the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RichFaces 4.3.x come in 4 jars:

- richfaces-core-api.jar
- richfaces-core-impl.jar
- richfaces-components-api.jar
- richfaces-components-ui.jar (here are the taglibs)

see the [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/Developer_Guide/en-US/html_single/#sect-Developer_Guide-Getting_started_with_RichFaces-Technical_Requirements-Project_libraries_and_dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'org.richfaces.core:richfaces-core-api:4.3.7.Final'
compile 'org.richfaces.core:richfaces-core-impl:4.3.7.Final'
compile 'org.richfaces.ui:richfaces-components-api:4.3.7.Final'
compile 'org.richfaces.ui:richfaces-components-ui:4.3.7.Final'
```

fixed it.